# Core Data, Does accessing relationship cause table lookup?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm using Core Data in my project. I have an entity, EntityMO that has a 1-to-many optional relationship with RelationMO.

When I make the call myEntity.myRelation in my code (to see if the RelationMO object exists), is that going to cause a table lookup every time? Or is there some black magic happening with Core Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or is there some black magic happening with Core Data?

Simply getting the object will usually not require accessing the data store, but the object you get in that case will be a *fault*, not the actual stored object. When you *use* the object, the fault will *fire*, causing the object to be realized. There are a few operations (e.g. `-isEqual:`) that will not cause a fault to fire -- see [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html) for more information.

Faults are realized behind the scenes and so may seem like black magic, but it's better to think of them as delayed gratification.